# Set environment variable on branch checkout/switch

Tags: windows, git, windows-subsystem-for-linux, githooks

I'm using the post-checkout hook to try and set environment variables when switching branches.

```bash
#!/bin/sh

echo "Updating environment variables..."

OLD_IFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'

for x in $(cat .env | sed -e '/^#/d;/^\s*$/d' -e "s/'/'\\\''/g" -e "s/=\(.*\)/='\1'/g")
do
    var_name=$( cut -d '=' -f 1 <<< "$x" )
    export $x
    pwsh.exe -c "\$env:$x"
    pwsh.exe -c "echo 1; echo \$env:$var_name"
    export $x
done

IFS=$OLD_IFS
```

The problem is that git hook is executed with WSL so the variables I set are lost after the post-hook

I assume this is because of the shebang?

I've tried `#!/usr/bin/env pwsh` but I get the error `Processing -File '.git/hooks/post-checkout' failed because the file does not have a '.ps1' extension. Specify a valid PowerShell script file name, and then try again.`

Is this something that can be done? I want to automatically change the DB connection when I switch branches.

Comment: variables set in a subprocess can't affect the parent process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [anthony sottlie noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74952160/set-environment-variable-on-branch-checkout-switch#comment132268822_74952160), you can't do it that way.

What you need instead is a command that you run *instead of* `git switch` or `git checkout`.  In this command, you will:

1. run `git switch` or `git checkout`, then
2. set the environment variables you *would have* set in your script, the way you *would have* set them

and since this will be done by the command itself, rather than in a subprocess, it will affect further commands run by this same command-line interpreter.